# Jquery load Problema

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Jquery Load

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.Charge1').load('Main.html');
    });
    </script>
```

tengo un Main.html <- en este html guarde el footer y el Menu

el Main.html esta asi [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

desde otro html usando el script me carga asi(Cabe resaltar que me asegure que las rutas del css estuvieran correctas)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que intento hacer, es incluir los elementos del Main.html en los otros html para que no se me haga repetitivo escribir las misma lineas del menu y footer.

Main.html(este es el documento que contiene el menu y el footer esto es lo que quiero pasar al Skills.html

```
<head>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#CT').load('Skills.html');
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>



        <!-- menu simple  -->
    <div class="caja" id="Caja">
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href = "index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li class="active-R"><a href = "aboutMe.html">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href = "Skills.html">Skills</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>


            <footer>
                <div class="footer">
                        <p class="Text">John <script> let CurrentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
                        document.write(CurrentYear)
                          </script></p>
                </div>
            </footer>
```

Skills.html(Aqui esta el Skills.html este es el html donde quiero poner el menu y footer

```
<head>
<script> src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


    <div id="CT"></div>
















</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Lo estás haciendo al revés.  En el main debes insertar los otros html.

Comment: ok no me esta resultando,  puse esto en el Main.html  ``` <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.Charge1').load('Main.html');
    });
    </script>  ```   y en el html donde quiero poner los elementos, puse el div con su id, es de esta forma la correcta?

Comment: ¿Y dónde está tu html? como para ayudar más.

Comment: el Main.html y el Skills.html están en la misma carpeta ¿te refieres a eso? Ahora me pregunto si hay alguna otra forma de hacer esto?

Answer (score 0):

El siguiente código representa la plantilla principal (main) donde se insertarán los otros archivos en el `div` con `id = contenido`:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#contenido').load('./archivoAInsertar.html');      

});

</script>


</head>


<body>


<div id="contenido">

</div>


</body>

</html>
```